# Mic sensitivity in Android CDD

Tags: android, microphone, android-compatibility

The Android Compatibility Definition Document states that

1. "Audio input sensitivity SHOULD be set such that a 90 dB sound power level (SPL) source at 1000 Hz yields RMS of 2500 for 16-bit samples".
2. "PCM amplitude levels SHOULD linearly track input SPL changes over at least a 30 dB range from -18 dB to +12 dB re 90 dB SPL at the microphone."

Questions:

Does (1) include Mic sensitivity plus the internal gain of android device to achieve RMS of 2500?

Is (2) for Mic maximum acoustic level only or includes internal of Android device?

Comment: Where is the connection to programming in this question?  The CDD appears more to be a guide to make _hardware_ compatible rather than _software_.

Comment: @CGT: Are you asking as an acoustic engineer trying to optimize the filter settings for a device, or as an app developer? In the former case, doesn't the Android CTS include tests for this? In the latter case, what exactly is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: My bad if not in right category. My 1st post. Indeed CDD is more Hardware. We are making voice recording device on Android. I'm unclear the ADC part in CDD. The mic sensitivity is -42 dB. How does it relate to RMS of 2500??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware development rather than programming

Answer (score 2):

Your questions are confusing me. I think you are mixing different levels and gains.

An acoustic level of 90dBspl rms is transfered into the electrical domain through the microphone. The microphone has a different acoustic unit for conversion. It measures sound pressure level in dBPa or Pa. (94dBspl = 0dBPa) The specified -42dBV/Pa means that if you have 0dBPa or 1Pa (which is the same sound pressure level) then you will get -42dBV out from the microphone in the analog electrical domain. -42dBV = 7.94mV  (0dBV =1V)

Now, from this point there can be different gains analog and digital. First you can have some analog gain and then you have an A/D converter. After that you are in the digital domain and then you can have digital gain as well. The Android requirement does not specify these gains. It specifies what final digital level you should have with a given acoustic sound pressure level. You can of course calculate each and every step inside the sound chain, but the easiast way is to set all digital gains to 0dB and maybe set the analog gain to something around +20dB (if possible), then you try to get an acoustic sound source with the proper sound pressure level. You will need a sound pressure level meter and a sinusoidal 1kHz tone played through a loudspeaker at maybe 20cm distance in a fairly non-reverberant echo-free room.

Now you record the 90dBspl 1kHz tone with your device and analyze the recording in the digital domain. If you can, you should adjust the gain in the analog domain. Then the digital headroom will be correct. If you do not know what you are doing you could easily try to adjust too much in the digital domain, leading to digital clipping or quantization noise. Digital gain should only put in when you have done everything you can in the analog domain.

If everything is correctly adjusted you will have a good matching between 90dBspl rms acoustic level and the recorded digital level of -22dBFS rms which is the level of 2500 rms in a 16 bit system (this is however a very strange way of measuring). 0dBFS rms is a fully saturated square wave in such a system. A fully saturated sinusoidal will have -3dBFS rms or 0dBFS peak.

Be aware of that if you have enabled any automatic gain control, you will probably not be able to comply with the requirement of linearity.